# Powershell $PSScriptRoot empty when using Invoke-Command

Tags: powershell

When running a .ps1 on a remote computer using Invoke-Command, $PSScriptRoot is empty on the remote computer.

Is this normal?  How can one find the .ps1 path when using Invoke-Command?

Further, other methods, such as through $MyInvocation are also empty.

Comment: my understanding is that `$PSScriptRoot` is filled in _when a script starts_ ... and `Invoke-Command` creates a new scope when it runs. that is why you need to use the `$Using:` scope modifier. ///// so  ... have you tried passing that $Var in like you are supposed to pass in any other variable? [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this normal? How can one find the .ps1 path when using Invoke-Command?

There is *no script file* involved on the *remote* computer when you call
`Invoke-Command -ComputerName $someComputer -FilePath c:\path\to\some\script.ps1`

What PowerShell does in this case is to send the *contents* (parsed source code)<sup>[1]</sup> of the caller-local script file to the remote machine and executes it there.

Therefore, `$PSScriptRoot` (the directory in which a script file resides) *doesn't apply* and returns the *empty string*.
The same applies to other script-*file*-related automatic variables, such as `$PSCommandPath` and `$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name` (see [about_Automatic_Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables)).

To put it differently: **When the script file's *code* executes remotely, it doesn't know anything about the *file* it came from on the caller's side.**

Thus, the only information available you there is `$PWD`, i.e., the current (working) location (directory).

---

<sup>[1] From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command): "When you use this [the `-FilePath`] parameter, PowerShell converts the contents of the specified script file to a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks), transmits the script block to the remote computer, and runs it on the remote computer."</sup>